Can someone explain how they simplified this algebra between these two lines?
I am looking at the solution to this problem and can't understand this algebra. I don't understand how they rewrote the expression as follows,
$$
\begin{align}
\bigl((1 − p)(1 − r)\bigr)^k p
&= \bigl((1 − p)(1 − r)\bigr)^{k−1} (1 − p)r 
+ \bigl((1 − p)(1 − r)\bigr)^k p \\
&= \bigl((1 − p)(1 − r)\bigr)^{k−1} (1 − p)(p + r − pr)
\end{align}
$$
This comes from a larger problem concerning a geometric distribution, where $p$ and $r$ are probabilities. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

This is just wrong. Test $p=0$.

Rewrite the first expression as:
$$\color{blue}{\big((1-p)(1-r)\big)^{k-1}}\color{green}{(1-p)r}+\color{blue}{\big((1-p)(1-r)\big)^{k-1}}\color{green}{(1-p)(1-r)p}$$
The blue factor appears in both the numbers so you can factor it out
$$\color{blue}{\big((1-p)(1-r)\big)^{k-1}}\big(\color{green}{(1-p)r}+\color{green}{(1-p)(1-r)p}\big) $$
The green part becomes
$$\color{green}{(1-p)r}+\color{green}{(1-p)(1-r)p}=\color{green}{(1-p)(r+p-rp)}$$
and then you get what you want.
Hope this helps. :)

Factoring $\bigl((1 − p)(1 − r)\bigr)^{k−1} (1 - p)$ out of both terms,
\begin{align}
&\phantom{{}={}} \bigl((1 − p)(1 − r)\bigr)^{k−1} (1 − p)r 
+ \bigl((1 − p)(1 − r)\bigr)^k p \\
&= \color{blue}{\bigl((1 − p)(1 − r)\bigr)^{k−1} (1 − p)}r 
+ \color{blue}{\bigl((1 − p)(1 − r)\bigr)^{k−1} (1 − p)}(1 - r)p \\
&= \color{blue}{\bigl((1 − p)(1 − r)\bigr)^{k−1} (1 − p)} 
\bigl(r + (1 - r)p \bigr) \\
&= \bigl((1 − p)(1 − r)\bigr)^{k−1} (1 − p) \bigl(p + r - pr \bigr).
\end{align}

Solved. Thank you!
